# Verifying cElementTree or elementTree node type

Tags: python, elementtree, python-unittest, celementtree

I have used cElementTree to parse XML files in my application and it works beautifully, however, now I wanted to write some unit tests to check whether the results of my methods return expected results.

In one of my tests I want to check whether a retrieved element from the tree is indeed an Element type:

```
self.assertIsInstance(myElem, Element, 'Incorrect type for myElem')
```

When I execute my test, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type or tuple of classes and types.
```

What is Element then if it is not a class or a type? I could not find many details about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this excerpt from the source code,
File : ElementTree.py

```
##
# Element factory.  This function returns an object implementing the
# standard Element interface.  The exact class or type of that object
# is implementation dependent, but it will always be compatible with
# the {@link #_ElementInterface} class in this module.
# <p>
# The element name, attribute names, and attribute values can be
# either 8-bit ASCII strings or Unicode strings.
#
# @param tag The element name.
# @param attrib An optional dictionary, containing element attributes.
# @param **extra Additional attributes, given as keyword arguments.
# @return An element instance.
# @defreturn Element

def Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra):
    attrib = attrib.copy()
    attrib.update(extra)
    return _ElementInterface(tag, attrib)
```

So, `Element` is ultimately a factory method.